# Auto.Arima using xreg giving xreg as insignificant

Tags: forecasting, arima

I am trying to forecast volume using ARIMA. I also have a independent variable that I can use in forecasting. When I do a normal linear Regression the Independent variable is very significant. But when I am doing an auto.arima model I got the following model:

```
ARIMA(3,1,3)
      Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
ar1   0.453844   0.043957  10.3248  < 2e-16 ***

ar2  -0.081913   0.046282  -1.7699  0.07675 .  

ar3  -0.510220   0.043070 -11.8463  < 2e-16 ***

ma1  -0.650601   0.033088 -19.6625  < 2e-16 ***

ma2  -0.654464   0.035819 -18.2714  < 2e-16 ***

ma3   0.664126   0.028016  23.7055  < 2e-16 ***

xreg  0.262486   0.355874   0.7376  0.46077
```

As you can see the independent variable(xreg) is insignificant here. How do I interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that [`auto.arima()` fits a regression with ARIMA errors](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

The key issue is the treatment of the intercept. `lm()` will *always* fit an intercept, but `auto.arima(..., allowmean=TRUE)` *may* do so (or remove it - there apparently is no way to *force* `auto.arima()` to include the intercept, unless you run `lm()` first, then call `auto.arima()` on the residuals).

Some playing around will give you different possible combinations (I'm truncating the output):

```
> set.seed(1)
> foo <- ts(rnorm(100))
> bar <- rnorm(100)
> summary(lm(foo~bar))

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.1088521  0.0903480   1.205    0.231
bar         -0.0009324  0.0947216  -0.010    0.992

> summary(auto.arima(foo,xreg=bar))

Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors 

Coefficients:
         xreg
      -0.0055
s.e.   0.0944
```

This is your situation: `lm ()` fits an intercept, `auto.arima()` doesn't, so the coefficients (and the standard errors, and p values) don't match. You can force these to match by excluding the intercept from the `lm()` model:

```
> summary(lm(foo~bar-1))

Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
bar -0.005456   0.094863  -0.058    0.954
```

Adding an offset induces `auto.arima()` to include the intercept:

```
> summary(lm(foo+1~bar))

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.1088521  0.0903480   12.27   <2e-16 ***
bar         -0.0009324  0.0947216   -0.01    0.992    

> summary(auto.arima(foo+1,xreg=bar))

Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors 

Coefficients:
      intercept     xreg
         1.1089  -0.0009
s.e.     0.0894   0.0938
```

And the coefficients and (mostly) the standard errors match again.